# Undefined local variable or method `acts_as_votable'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to use the acts_as_votable gem in Rails 5.2, using [this tutorial](https://www.devwalks.com/lets-build-instagram-part-5-liking-larrys-legs-step-one/).

I've followed all the steps and read the documentation, but for some reason I keep getting a NameError.

This is my Post Model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_votable

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :comments
  has_many :reactions

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :url, use: :slugged

end
```

My Gemfile:

```
gem "acts_as_votable"
```

Screenshot:
[Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qpxY.png)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you restarted your server since you've added the gem? You need to restart your rails server whenever you add/remove gems.

Comment: Yeah, I've also tried updating the gem. Can't figure out what's going wrong, I feel like I've probably made a stupid mistake somewhere.

Comment: Yeah a couple of times, my first thought was that the gem wasn't installed.